# Using style from another assembly in Metro application

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I start with the Windows 8 C# [XAML user and custom controls sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-user-and-custom-a8a9505e) and moved the files

```
Themes/Generic.xaml
BasicCustomControl.cs
BasicUserControl.xaml
BasicUserControl.xaml.cs
ImageWithLabelControl.cs
```

to a Metro Class Library named `Controls`, reference it in the `UserAndCustomControls` project and correct the `local:...` references to `xmlns:local="using:Controls"`. This works great.

BUT if create a resource dictionary `"Style.xaml"` in the class library with

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Controls">
    <Color x:Key="ColorBackground">Red</Color>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and include in the `ScenarioList.xaml` file

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Controls;component/Style.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

i'm get an runtime error

```
XamlParseException
Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary.Source'.
```

if I try apply the color to the Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ColorBackground}" />
    </Grid.Background>

    <ListBox x:Name="Scenarios" ...
    [...]
</Grid>
```

**[Q]** The question is, how do I correctly declare, reference and use external style in Metro application? My idea is create reusable controls and common styles delivered as a single dll file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[navits](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/bcb480d1-cb7c-4d36-ba92-9c513d95e51a) points the answer.

If you have a dll named "CustomControl" with a ResourceDictionary
named "Styles.xaml" contained a folder named "Themes".

For C# projects the App.xaml should contain :

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///CustomControls/Themes/Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**With** the `Themes` folder in the Source path, for C# projects.

and

For VB.Net projects the App.xaml should contain :

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///CustomControls/Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Without** the `Themes` folder in Source path, for VB.Net projects.

Answer (score 10):

Your Source path is wrong as the component syntax is not supported.  Assuming your control library DLL is called "Controls" then it would be like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Controls/Files/Style.xaml" />
```

You can look at http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx for a deeper explanation.

Comment: I do not have a separate DLL for Resorce Dictionary, but I have it under "Common" folder in the same .csproj and I am including the path as `<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Common//MyResourceDictionary.xaml"/>` in App.xaml. But, I am still getting the same error ???

Comment: This answer works, but it is very important to note that it will not if your referenced assembly's name contains whitespaces or dots and possibly also other non-alphanumeric characters. It's a bug in Visual Studio 2012 that almost drove me nuts until I tried a different project name for the library

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that you can also use the **pack** notation to get a resource from the referenced assembly, and it works also if its name contains a dot:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AtlasInformatics.UI;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In this example the standard 'Generic.xaml' of a library with controls is imported into the ResourceDictionary of the 'App.xaml' to let the Visual Studio designer show the controls the same way as it would during runtime.